# LI-ion charging: Should I turn off the charging circuit to measure battery voltage?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I'm working on a 120VAC smart sensor product that contains a single internal soldered-on LI-ion cell to provide backup power for up to 24 hours after power failure with reduced functionality. I know that LI-ion charging would normally have a CC (constant current) phase and then switch to a CV (constant voltage) phase as it nears full charge, and discussions about charging algorithms talk about measuring the battery voltage during charging, but I haven't found anything that discusses *how* to measure the battery voltage: It seems to me that measuring the voltage while the charging circuit is "on" would artificially inflate the voltage measurement beyond the true battery voltage.

Should I briefly turn off the charging circuit when measure the battery voltage to measure the battery's open-circuit voltage? Or would that actually be bad? I was imagining that the charging circuit would be off about 2 to 5 milliseconds while the MCU takes an open-circuit voltage measurement, and that such measurements would be made every 1 to 5 seconds; is this reasonable? Can anyone offer researched or experiential guidance on this?

I found these pages that also discuss what I'm asking, but nobody gives any clear answers to my own question:

- [Maximum *charging* voltage for Li-Ion battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93892/68634) - The OP discusses "Vcell -> voltage when PWM is OFF" and "Vchg -> voltage when PWM is ON", but it doesn't discuss when or how often these measurements should be made.
- [Battery voltage measurement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/574335/68634) - Discusses the issue (voltage measurement difference between charging-circuit-on vs. charging-circuit-off) but treats it as more of a "known issue" and doesn't answer what to do about it.
- [Measuring Li-Ion Battery voltage during charging/discharging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/202176/68634) - Mentions the issue but assumes the measurement discrepancy might be compensated by some sort of calculation, but the comments and the only posted answer don't seem to really address it.
- [ATMEL AVR450 Battery Charger application note - AVR450.pdf](http://www.professordan.com/avr/techlib/techlib8/appnotes/pdf_avr/AVR450.pdf) - Ever-so-briefly mentions on page 17, "The real-time clock is started when the PWM is started, and is also stopped when the PWM is stopped, i.e., when the battery voltage is measured." ...but doesn't discuss how often or for how long this occurs.

Comment: The cell voltage will be no higher than the voltage measured with the charger connected, and you only want to be certain not to exceed 4.2 V. Have you got the equipment to monitor the power input to a commercial charger? That way, you could see if there are dips in the power input which would correspond to the charger pausing for a moment - although the caps in the PSU might scupper that idea. On the other hand, I suspect that it would need several seconds for the cell to "relax" after the charge current is disconnected for the cell voltage to settle, *if* it does relax.

Comment: I just noticed, in the AVR450 app note you linked to there is a flow chart for "4.3.1 int battery" which shows that the PWM is switched off before reading the cell voltage and it waits until the ADC gets a reasonably stable reading before resuming the PWM. (It looks like if the cell voltage doesn't stabilise, it keeps waiting.) Other chargers may behave differently.

Comment: And it only switches off the charging to measure the voltage when, and I didn't look closely, it is in one of either the CC or CV modes. For the actual timings, you could look at the source code.

Comment: Or you could use a dedicated charging IC.